# How to copy text from div to Clipboard in JS

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to use [zeroclipboard 2.2.0](http://zeroclipboard.org/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <script src="bower_components/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="first">1111111</div>
<div id="second">2222222222</div>

<button id="d_clip_button" class="my_clip_button" data-clipboard-target="first">Copy from first div</button>
<button data-clipboard-target="second">Copy from second div</button>
</body>
</html>
```

But it is not working for me. Could you point at mistake? I cannot find proper examples because they are quite oudated.

If you can suggest any alternative to zeroclipboard I will consider it.

Comment: I think, you need `input/textarea` elements where we can paste the copied text. You are using `div`. Try replacing the `div` by `textbox`

Comment: Hmm, seem that it should work with divs as well. See [line #996 in ZeroClipboard.js](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/dist/ZeroClipboard.js#L996)  (it's quite long, scroll it)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<div id="first">1111111</div>
<div id="second">2222222222</div>

<button id="button1" data-clipboard-target="first">Copy from first div</button>
<button id="button2" data-clipboard-target="second">Copy from second div</button>

<script>
    var zeroClipboard = new ZeroClipboard();
    zeroClipboard.clip(document.querySelector("#button1"));
    zeroClipboard.clip(document.querySelector("#button2"));

    zeroClipboard.on('copy', function(event) {

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt use that, if you want, here a code without zeroclipboard 2.2.0.

**HTML**

```
<div id="first">1111111</div>
<div id="second">2222222222</div>


<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#first')">Copy from first div</button>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#second')">Copy from second div</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```